# How can I create a query to sum values and obtain a total in my database?

Tags: vba, ms-access, sum

I have a query that totals my lesson duration to give me a course hours. I am having trouble writing the code to pull the recordset.

The result I get, using the code I am trying to learn to write, appears to count the rows in the query but not get the value of the sum of *LessonDuration*.

```
Function Cduration() As Integer

    Dim SQL As String
    Dim dbs As Database, rst As Recordset

        SQL = "SELECT Course_tbl.CatalogID, Sum(Lessons_tbl.LessonDuration) AS [Course Duration] " & _
                "FROM (ListModule_tbl INNER JOIN Course_tbl ON ListModule_tbl.[ModuleID] = Course_tbl.[ModuleID]) " & _
                "INNER JOIN Lessons_tbl ON Course_tbl.[CourseID] = Lessons_tbl.[CourseID] " & _
                "GROUP BY Course_tbl.CatalogID;"

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(SQL)
        Cduration = rst.Fields(1)
    rst.Close
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Yes, It shows the results correctly. I included a screenshot of the Query. One course hours shoule reflect 2.5 hrs. and the seconc course should reflect 4.0 hrs.

Comment: If you have a saved query object and want only one value from that query, could use DLookup() to pull in VBA: `DLookup("[Course Duration]", "qryCourseDuration")`. Advise not to use spaces in naming convention.

Comment: The field I am trying to populate is in my main report. I could not figure out how to get the value from the query into the unbound field. Or how to get the value from the query into the related course table.

Comment: Domain aggregate functions can be used in query and textbox expression as well as in VBA. They can slow performance of query or form with large dataset. You say you want to populate a field or an UNBOUND textbox? Saving aggregate data to field is usually unnecessary and can be risky. If it can be calculated for UPDATE, it can be calculated when needed.

Comment: Without filter criteria or moving to appropriate row of recordset, return will always be from first row of query, regardless of CatalogID of record main form has focus on.

Comment: @June7 I did try =DLookUp("[SumofLessonDuration]","qryCourseDuration","CatalogID=" & [CatalogID]). I receive a #Error in the field.

Comment: Field name in posted query is [Course Duration]. Also, CatalogID shows a text value. If it really is text field, then need apostrophe delimiters.

Comment: @June7, Sorry for the confusion. I did name the field in the query from SumofLessonDuration to Course Duration:SumofLessonDuration. I then changed it back because I thought the renaming the field in the query design view might have been the reason I could not get a proper result.

Comment: Okay, use whatever alias field name is in query object. Text field requires apostrophe delimiters for parameter `"CatalogID='" & [CatalogID] & "'"`.

Comment: I Used =DLookUp("[SumofLessonDuration]","qryCourseDuration","CatalogID='" & [CatalogID] & "'") and now I get a 1 in the field if the course has lessons and nothing in the field if the course does not have lessons.

Comment: Not knowing your data, can't explain that. Just as I cannot explain why your recordset fails. Your code works for me with a simple SQL. You could post in a discussion forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: Sorry. New to this site. I will look for discussion forums. Thank you for the help. I feel I am getting closer.

Comment: Is there a collective you would recommend for this type of question?

Comment: Google "access forums", possibilities: accessforums.net, access-programmers.co.uk, utteraccess.com, vbaexpress.com.

Comment: @June7 do all the forums you recommend allow attaching files?

Comment: Yes, that's why I listed them.